# Getting my postgresql db version?

Tags: postgresql, sqlite, postgresql-9.5

On SQlite I could do a query for `PRAGMA user_version;` and I could set the version if need be too.  Is there anything in postgres that could do the same thing?

I tried `select version()` but that gets the literal version of postgres, and not a custom set version.

As an update: I researched commenting on databases. Perhaps this could be solution... [commenting docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-comment.html)

Comment: what you mean custom set?

Comment: What I mean is that if I create a fresh Person DB, I can set the `user_version=1`.  Sometime later I create a migration that updates something and then after I set the `user_version=2`.

Comment: You can use something like [Liquibase](http://liquibase.org/) to manage your database schema. That will keep track of all changes that you have applied

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set a custom configuration parameter. The parameter name must contain a dot, e.g.:

```
set my.version to 4;
select current_setting('my.version') as version;

 version 
---------
 4
(1 row)
```

A parameter defined in this way is local to the current session. If you want to define a default value for the parameter for all sessions you can add it to the configuration file `postgresql.conf` (for all databases in the server). Alternatively, it is possible to set the default value for a database in the command:

```
set my.version to 4;
alter database my_database set my.version from current;
```

See also:

- [Setting Parameters](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/config-setting.html)
- [Customized Options](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-custom.html)
- [ALTER DATABASE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterdatabase.html)

Comment: And what if I wanted it to persist across sessions?

Comment: Cool! I wont be able to test this out until tomorrow when I can mark it as the answer or not.  But conceptually, I don't see why it would not work.  Any consideration as to why setting the db version as comment is not a good idea?

Comment: Using comments for this purpose is of course possible but clumsy, you have to query a system catalog to retrieve a database comment. Custom parameter is a more natural and easier solution.

Comment: would you happen to know how to remove the custom parameter after it has been set?

Comment: I think you cannot remove a local custom parameter (set in a session). For a database - use `alter database my_database reset my.version;` (the effect will be visible in next sessions, not in the current one)